# How to protect the access of a Docker container

Tags: security, unix, docker

Is it possible to prevent the root user (and also other users) of one host machine to access the content of a Docker image or container in case he hasn't docker credentials?

Comment: This may have already been answered over on Security Stack Exchange...

Comment: do you have the link to it please?

Comment: I think this one may cover what you need: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/167840/485 but check https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=docker for other questions on docker security